# Is there a way to make python skip an operation if it takes too long to calculate

Tags: python, numbers, expression

I need to iterate through a lot of expressions and calculate all of them. However some result in a huge number and take way too long to calculate on my laptop. I want to skip them, but don't know how.

```
result = 0

for arrangement in arrangements:
    try:
        exec('result = ' + arrangement)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
    if isinstance(result, int):
        print(result)
        if result > 0 and 100 > result and result % 1 == 0:
            results[arrangement] = result
            ordered[int(result)] = arrangement
```

I get arrangements of numbers and operators that i need to calculate as strings, for example `'(4**factorial(2**3)**1)'`

It runs the first calculations, then freezes and stops responding when it hits something like `factorial(2+1)**factorial(3**4)`, so i hope there is a way to skip those, make "time out" or something.

Comment: You can raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` with `<C-c>`.

Comment: @gilch but i wnat to to do the other calculations after skipping this one

Comment: `multiprocessing ` has a `argument` that throws an exception when the time goes over. Only other thought is that you use the `threading` module and write your own timeout func

Comment: You can catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` like any other exception. Also check out the `signal` module. You can use it to set up other handlers for asynchronous events. The `KeyboardInterrupt` uses `SIGINT`. You could raise (and catch) a custom exception type in response to some other signal.

Comment: Have you tried checking out the multithreading ways to do this. I do not have much experience with multithreading in python but there might be ways such that you can start the task in a new thread and wait for a max threshold time for the task to be completed. If task does not completes within threshold time you can just move to the next task.